# Making a drop-down list for launching a model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, value-list

Is that possible to make a model in which you can choose what certain model you are going to run?
For example I have a list of models like:

- Roads intersections detector level-1
- Roads intersections detector level-2
- Roads intersections detector level-3

And I want to create a model with a drop-down list with values which are names of that models I have in my toolbox. When value is selected the model launches certain submodel.

Comment: Yes.  Have you tried creating three models that do something simple like copying a feature class to a different name for each (so you know which one ran), then added them to your model which you configure with a pick list?

Comment: @PolyGeo some of my models have pick lists and work with a same layer of roads. But one of them, for instance, needs to be checked with layer of quarters, another by town or village. So due to convenience for other users I would like to make something like a choice of what kind of model they are going to run.

Comment: Exactly, but the place where you are stuck is the little model over the top.  While you are figuring out how to make that you can use three test submodels (like I described).  That way you get quicker test cycles and can show us all the components if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done but requires a small bit of coding and you setting names, labels and aliases, none of which can be ignored.

**Step 1 - Create a master model**

Create the master model that will be the drop down list. Add a string variable and make it a parameter then set the value list to user friendly terms as shown below:

[image: Setting value list]

**Step 2 - Create your 3 models that you want to execute independently**

Use a standard *Name* and set the *Label* to be the text that was in the drop down, as shown below:

[image: Setting model properties]

**Step 3 - Add a calculate value tool to master model**

Note that the code imports the toolbox then calls the individual model by its Name (so not label),underscore then the toolbox alias (which I had set to myToolBox).

[image: Code]

The full python code is as:

```py
import arcpy
def run(mod):
  try:
    arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"F:\Scratch\Toolbox.tbx")
    if mod == "model 1":
      arcpy.mod1_myToolBox1()
    elif mod == "my model 2":
      arcpy.mod2_myToolBox()
    else:
      arcpy.mod3_myToolBox()
    return True
  except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
    return False
```

Comment: thanks for a detailed instruction! I made it all the way you show but I've got an error like `Error running expression: run("Obj_checker_local") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in run  IOError: The toolbox file F:\Scratch\Toolbox.tbx was not found. ` 
Obj_checker is a label of one of my models

Comment: F:\Scratch\Toolbox.tbx is my toolbox, I do not know where yours is or named, so you need to edit that line of code. I had created a toolbox with the master model and the 3 to be run all within a single toolbox. Also if you look very carefully I left in a deliberate error arcpy.mod1_myToolBox1(). My toolbox alias is myToolBox not *myToolBox1*.

Comment: okay, I will try to fix that, thank you one more time!